# Pandas return value from multiple columns if equal to value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
  A      B        C         D
0 month   month+1 quarter+1 season+1
1 season  month+5 quarter+3 season+2
2 day     month+1 quarter+2 season+1
3 year    month+3 quarter+4 season+2
4 quarter month+2 quarter+1 season+1
5 month   month+4 quarter+1 season+2
```

I would like to insert a new column called 'E' based on several IF conditions. If column 'A' equals 'month' then return values in 'B', if column 'A' equals 'quarter' then return values in 'C', if column 'A' equals 'season' then return values in 'D', and if not then return values in column 'A'

```
  A      B        C         D        E
0 month   month+1 quarter+1 season+1 month+1
1 season  month+5 quarter+3 season+2 season+2
2 day     month+1 quarter+2 season+1 day
3 year    month+3 quarter+4 season+2 year
4 quarter month+2 quarter+1 season+1 quarter+1
5 month   month+4 quarter+1 season+2 month+4
```

I am having trouble doing this. I have tried playing around with a function but it did not work. See my attempt:

```
def f(row):
    if row['A'] == 'month':
        val = ['B']
    elif row['A'] == 'quarter':
        val = ['C']
    elif row['A'] == 'season':
        val = ['D']
    else:
        val = ['A']
    return val

df['E'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

EDITED: to change the last `else` to column 'A'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `np.select`

```
c1 = df['A'] == 'month'
c2 = df['A'] == 'quarter'
c3 = df['A'] == 'season'

df['E'] = np.select([c1, c2, c3], [df['B'], df['C'], df['D']], df['A'])

Out[271]:
         A        B          C         D          E
0    month  month+1  quarter+1  season+1    month+1
1   season  month+5  quarter+3  season+2   season+2
2      day  month+1  quarter+2  season+1        day
3     year  month+3  quarter+4  season+2       year
4  quarter  month+2  quarter+1  season+1  quarter+1
5    month  month+4  quarter+1  season+2    month+4
```

Comment: @ansev: He mentioned that his code doesn't work. His desired ouput is what he wants. My output matches his desired output. You solution is actually wrong because you base on his incomplete codes

Comment: @ansev: I quote OP words :  `I have tried playing around with a function but it did not work. See my attempt`. HIs description: `..... if not then return values in column 'A'.....`

Comment: True, he wrote else ['D'] but he said that by default it should be 'A', I didn't see it, +1

Comment: I would use `df['A']` instead `df.A`, because OP could try `df.T`

Answer (score 4):

Frist, I recommend you see: [`When should I want to use apply() in my code.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

I would use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

```
df['E'] = df['A'].replace(['month','quarter','season'],
                          [df['B'], df['C'], df['D']])
```

or [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
cond = [df['A'].eq('month'), df['A'].eq('quarter'), df['A'].eq('season')]
values= [df['B'], df['C'], df['D']]
df['E']=np.select(cond,values,default=df['A'])
```

---

```
  A      B        C         D        E
0 month   month+1 quarter+1 season+1 month+1
1 season  month+5 quarter+3 season+2 season+2
2 day     month+1 quarter+2 season+1 day
3 year    month+3 quarter+4 season+2 year
4 quarter month+2 quarter+1 season+1 quarter+1
5 month   month+4 quarter+1 season+2 month+4
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to fix your code like this:

```
def f(row):
    if row['A'] == 'month':
        val = row['B']
    elif row['A'] == 'quarter':
        val = row['C']
    elif row['A'] == 'season':
        val = row['D']
    else:
        val = row['D']
    return val

df['E'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

note: you forgot to include `row`

```
val = ['B'] # before
val = row['B'] # after
```

Edit: This is just to point out the problem in the code, for better approaches check out the other answers related to the usage of [numpy.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Comment: I just showed what was wrong in the code, wasn't trying to optimize